# Reset submission

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a reset function I can use on client side form to reset their selections and start over?

Our form has multiple options to choose from - but if you change one option the others do not change.  I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Are you trying to provide a way for users to "start over" or do you want to allow them to select options up front and conditionally show the appropriate additional questions based on their selection?

Comment: Hi Jamie - "start over" and I came back to take my question down because I figured it out!  They just reload the page, right?  I love this form.  Just love it.  Thanks for all your help and for being here!!  I've got the conditional logic figured out, too, thanks to you.  Smiles!  Deborah

Comment: Glad it's working! I'll answer the question with exactly what you figured out.  It may be obvious in hindsight, but we have answered this question many many times.

Comment: Thanks again, Jamie - I did do a search but it didn't come up.

Answer (score 1):

You can "reset" forms in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) by refreshing the page the user is on, such as having a reset link or button that simply takes the user back to the page they are on.  Each time the page loads, the form will reset to the initial default view.